# React Hooks, state not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I m new to react and js.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Forminput = () => {
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({}); //state values
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
  }); //state values

  const change = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const submitChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(values);
    setErrors(validation(values));
    console.log(errors);
  };

  const validation= (values) => {
    if (!values.username.trim()) {
      errors.username = "Username required";
    }

    if (!values.email) {
      errors.email = "Email required";
    } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(values.email)) {
      errors.email = "Email address is invalid";
    }

    return errors;
  };

  useEffect(() => {}, [errors]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Create Your Form </h2>
      <form action="" className="form-inputs" onSubmit={submitChange}>
        <div className="username">
          <label htmlFor="username" className="username">
            Username
          </label>
          <input
            id="username"
            type="text"
            className="username"
            name="username"
            onChange={change}
            value={values.username}
          />
          {errors.username && <p>{errors.username}</p>}
        </div>

        <div className="email">
          <label htmlFor="email" className="email">
            email
          </label>
          <input
            id="email"
            type="text"
            name="email"
            className="email"
            onChange={change}
            value={values.email}
          />
          {errors.email && <p>{errors.email}</p>}
        </div>

        <input type="submit" className="signup" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

setErrors state is not updating.

1. Two fields username and email. when entered username and not email first for time the errors state is updating.
2. when entered again right email then press submit it is not updating the error state but updating the values state. i tried using useeffect() but not working.

i new here could you please me.

I want to update the errors state too when i update values state. is this right way or help me

Comment: I know another solution. like we can initialize to empty object and then set it to set errors after validation. but I don't wanna use empty object. thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: no yassin. could you help me???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're mutating the `errors` object in `validation` and setting the same `errors` object when you call `setErrors` in `submitChange`. Since `errors` is the same object reference, this doesn't trigger a re-render. You'll need to return a new object from `validation`:

```
  const validation= (values) => {
    const result = {};

    if (!values.username.trim()) {
      result.username = "Username required";
    }

    if (!values.email) {
      result.email = "Email required";
    } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(values.email)) {
      result.email = "Email address is invalid";
    }

    return result;
  };
```

Comment: Also one doesn't need to use useEffect  here. useEffect is used only to do something AFTER rendering the component.

Comment: Thanks, alurv and nabil for the quick solution